# Node Socketio Websocket on Subdomain

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io, subdomain

Since weeks I am trying to implement my websocket functionality on my production (ubuntu) Server (nginx). My websockets work locally, but I Keep getting Errors on production.

My socket.js Looks like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var options = {
    type: "local",
    key: fs.readFileSync("/etc/nginx/ssl/sub.domain.com/467605/server.key"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync("/etc/nginx/ssl/sub.domain.com/467605/server.crt")
};
if (options.type == 'dev') {
    var app = require('http').createServer(handler);
} else {
    var app = require('http').createServer(options,handler);
}
var io    = require('socket.io')(app);
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis();

function handler(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end('');
}

io.on('connection', function(socket) {});

// Redis UserSignedUp Channel, Channel if user signs up
var redisUserSignedUp = new Redis();

redisUserSignedUp.subscribe('signed-up-channel');

redisUserSignedUp.on('message', function(channel, message) {
    message = JSON.parse(message);
    io.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data);
});
// run server on port 3333
app.listen(3333, function () {
    console.log('Server running!');
});
```

My Event.js Looks like this:

```
const socket = io('sub.domain.com:3333', {
    secure: true
});

// ... works locally
socket.on('signed-in-channel:App\\Events\\UserSignedIn', (data) => {
    this.signedInUsers = data.username;
    this.$toasted.info('Success: ' + data.username, {
        theme: "primary",
        duration: 10000
    });
});
```

If I do this in my Event.js:

```
const socket = io('sub.domain.com:3333', { secure: true });
```

I get this error:

> https://sub.domain.com:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MdZoLnn
>   net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Where as if I watch for the Server ip like this:

```
const socket = io('123.123.123.123:3333', { secure: true });
```

I get this error:

> https://123.123.123.123:3333/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MdZpRnE
>   net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

The site has an let's encrypt ssl certificate, further the webserver is nginx and the os is ubuntu. On my local window (wamp) it works starting it with node socket.js.